# Make discordbot wait for one of many replies from a user?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

So I have the code that makes a bot wait for the user to reply with a specific word, in this case it's "hello". But what if there are multiple things the user can reply with?

What if the bot says "Choose A, B or C". How do I make it wait for the user to reply with one of these answers?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send(f'Hello {msg.author}!')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this would work for you

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Choose A, B or C')

        def check(m):
            return m.content in ['A','B','C'] and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send(f'You choosed {msg.content}!')
```

Comment: It works, thank you.
I had the same idea but didn't know how to write it, I did try something like m.content == "A" or "B"...

Comment: @Scar You could do it this day, but it's going to be longer, like `(m.content == 'A' or m.content == 'B' or m.content == 'C')`. Good luck with your bot!